# Overriding Content-Length header with Rack/Sinatra

Tags: sinatra, rack

In Sinatra, how can I override the `Content-Length` header in the response to set my own value?

The last line in my method returns the following:

```
[200, {'Content-Type' => component.content_type,
'Content-Length' => component.content_length.to_s}, component.content.data]
```

This way I was hoping to override the content value, but it results in an exception:

```
Unexpected error while processing request: Content-Length header was 2, but should be 0
```

I would like to return a different value for the content length. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to override content-length – that can surely only cause problems. The behaviour depends on which server you’re using (I can’t reproduce the error you see with any of the default servers Sinatra uses). What are you trying to do?

Comment: In this case the user agent is an SAP system that is querying the data and is expecting the length of a document but not the document itself, i.e. it is interpreting the data in its own way. I am using Thin, if that makes any difference, although I am thinking that Rack is handling the adding of content length, as I understand there is a middleware for it, something I haven't quite grasped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is being raised by the [`Rack::Lint` middleware](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.5.2/lib/rack/lint.rb#L631), so the quick fix would be to not use that piece of middleware. Depending on how you are starting your application that may be tricky though – Rack adds it in certain cases if you use `rackup`.

A better solution would be to change your client to use a [HTTP `HEAD` request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) rather than a `GET`. In Sinatra [defining a `GET` route automatically defines a matching `HEAD` route](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1358-L1359). Using `HEAD` will cause the server to send the headers but not the body, and you should be able to set the `Content-Length` to whatever you want. It will also avoid the `Rack::Lint` error.

Here is a gist explaining how to disable `Rack::Lint`:

```
module Rack
  class Lint
    def call(env = nil)
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

(Taken from https://gist.github.com/shtirlic/2146256).

Comment: Yes, using a HEAD request makes more sense. Unfortunately for this user agent, standards compliance was not a priority, and changing it is not an option :-( However, can I replace a certain piece of middleware for only one specific route? Do you have a link to a code sample or something you can paste here that explains how to do this?

Comment: Also, I don't think I want o disable Rack::Lint completely. Now that I know it is there, I don't want that safety net feeling to go.

Comment: Thanks, I am going with your suggestion for disabling Rack::Lint, as it seems the quickest for now until I find a better way.

Comment: @mydoghasworms if you know the client isn’t going to look at the actual content another option would be to send a generated string of the length you want, something like `'-' * length`.